# Apply ColorFiltered to a container

Tags: flutter

I want to apply the widget ColorFiltered to a container which is inside an other container, the problem is the filter takes all the screen => The filter is also applied to the blue container, and this same container expands.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body:Test1()),
    );
  }
}


class Test1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 300,
        width: MediaQuery.of(
          context,
        ).size.width,
        child: Align(
            child: ColorFiltered(
          colorFilter:
              const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey, BlendMode.saturation),
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please insert the complete code you're using? Testing your code I see a blue container with height = 300 and a red container, with the color filter applied, in the center.

Comment: There is just: Scaffold(body: const Test1());

Comment: I still see the correct result, a blue container with a gray square, I think that you have some other widgets messing things up (ps using Flutter 3.3.9)

Comment: @LorenzOliveto ok, it works on mobile but it doesn't on web

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a Flutter issue, tracked [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98809).

One workaround suggested in the issue is to wrap the container in a `ClipRect` Widget like this:

```dart
class Test1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 300,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Align(
        child: ClipRect(
          child: ColorFiltered(
            colorFilter:
                const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey, BlendMode.saturation),
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I think I prefer to use Opacity instead in my case, for performances.